# Need to see the object limits in salesforce - single page

Tags: object

Is there any standard functionality that we have in Salesforce to see
how many custom fields are used for each object?

The current options that I can see are,

1. For standard object, we can go to setup -> customization -> object ->Limits
2. For custom objects , setup -> objects -> object -> object limits

My client asked me about do we have any option to see these details in a single page.

Below are the images of two standard objects and their limitations. I am looking for something to see both the object limitations in a single page.
[image][image]
I checked some forums and didn't get any answers.

Comment: Each of those show you the limits for an object on a single page. Are you asking to see ALL Objects on a single page? If so i do not think there is

Comment: @Eric, Thanks.  Do we any options to see it in single page ?

Comment: Define "it" .....You already have it in one page for each object

Comment: sorry. for the confusion. I want to see All objects limitations in a single page. For ex, I have 3 objects called Account , Contact and Lead. I can see those object limits by going for each object Limit details through setup option.  I am looking for something where I can see those 3 object details in single page. I think you're answer is clear for me. As of now, salesforce don't have any feature like that. I edited my question now.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no Out of the box functionality within Salesforce that allows you to view all the limits of x desired objects into one single page.